# daydream menu icon for Unity 5.5.4

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, icons, google-vr, daydream

So I have ran into a pickle that I can not find a solution for on the internet. 
I have an older project that was created before the native integration of google Vr into Unity. I am trying to make a daydream port for it. I have everything working great, the issue is creating the daydream menu icon! All the answers I find are for the latest version of unity, Which has the ability to upload the foreground and background images right through the editor. unfortunate that option is not available in Unity 5.5.4. Now the SDK that I have has build in Daydream support for my version of Unity, so I am assuming it is possible to upload these images without this native integration. 
Does anyone know how I might go about doing this? or can point me in the right direction?

Thank you.

Comment: Time to upgrade ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and apologies for the slow response.

I think the official advice would unfortunately be that it's time to upgrade.  The native integration came a while back.  If that's totally not an option for you, this might be less of a 'Daydream' question and more of an Android question.

Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Unity 5.5 is not supported for Daydream development.  Please use Unity 5.6 or later and preferably the latest GVR SDK for Unity.